# How to pass environment variables into .gitlab-ci.yml in Gitlab for Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab

I have setup the `application.properties` the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${SERVER_IP}/database
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

To be able to package the application, the environment variables has to be passed into the Maven command something like that:

```
mvn -DSERVER_IP=111.111.11.1111:5432 -DPOSTGRES_USER=user -DPOSTGRES_PASSWORD="password" package
```

In the .gitlab-ci.yml, I need to pass in these environment variables

```
maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn {what should I write here?} package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

I understand that first in Gitlab's setting the environment variables has to be defined, but how should I reference those environment variables in the .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the required Environment Variables in your `Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Environment Variables`.

And then in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` just [reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts) them as such :

```
script: mvn -DSERVER_IP=$SERVER_IP -DPOSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER -DPOSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD package -B
```

NB: From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables):

> Important: Be aware that variables are not masked, and their values
>   can be shown in the job logs if explicitly asked to do so. If your
>   project is public or internal, you can set the pipelines private from
>   your [project’s Pipelines settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#visibility-of-pipelines). Follow the discussion in issue
>   [#13784](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13784) for masking the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to use any environment variable in SpringBoot application, it not really needed to define Environment Variables in **GitLab -> CI/CD Settings**. It can be passed from the gitlab task with variables.

Below is the sample.

SpringBoot Application Config where we expect a Env Variable named **MYAPP_API_BASE**, whose value should be added to **myapplication.api-base**

```
myapplication:
  api-base: ${MYAPP_API_BASE}
```

Below is the GitLab Job example. Here we are executing functional-tests which require the container to be launched for my-app against the image already created. However while launching the application in the container we want to pass the value of **MYAPP_API_BASE** to spring boot.

```
functional-tests:
  stage: test
  image: openjdk:17-alpine
  variables:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    MYAPP_API_BASE: http://myapp:9020
  services:
    - name: wiremock/wiremock:main-alpine
      alias: mock-app
      command: [ "--port","9010","--https-port","9040","--verbose"]
    - name: my-app/version1
      alias: my-application
```

As shown above, the variable defined in job **MYAPP_API_BASE: http://myapp:9020** will be passed to the spring boot application which is launched from **my-app/version1** image