# Use Gitlab CI/CD variables in YAML file

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have got a YAML configuration file in which I need to store an API key. As I do not want to commit my API Key to my Repo I figured a Gitlab CI/CD variable would be a good option. I have configured the variable in the Gitlab UI to be:

`TOKEN = "123"`

My `.gitlab.ci.yml` file contains:

```
image:
  name: xxx
variables:
  P_TOKEN: ${TOKEN}
```

And my YAML file has:

```
spec:
  command: test.sh
  env_vars:
  - TOKEN=${P_TOKEN}
```

But it just sets `TOKEN` in the YAML file to `${P_TOKEN}` instead of the contents of `${P_TOKEN}`. If I echo out my variables in my CI/CD pipeline it is set correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables into .gitlab-ci.yml in Gitlab for Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914858/how-to-pass-environment-variables-into-gitlab-ci-yml-in-gitlab-for-spring-boot)

Comment: No, I want to use my configured gitlab variable in an external YAML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your YAML file is actually a *template* for a YAML file. You'd need to run some sort of template engine on top of it to have your `${P_TOKEN}` placeholder replaced.

A very simple example using `sed` that might suffice for your use case:

```bash
sed -i "s/\${P_TOKEN}/$TOKEN/" your_file.yaml
```